# Is quake3/ioquake's OOP good to do a large game?

Tags: c++, c, quake3

Everybody heard about the release of the Quake3 source code.

But since it's plain C but uses OOP a little, isn't it too complex to decipher or to use for large projects such as a 3rd person shooter/hack&slash with smooth camera movements ?

Would it be a good idea to use it instead of Ogre, I want to be sure it's really harder to use since it's only an engine dedicated to FPS.

Ogre seems to be a standard OSS, especially when thinking about OOP, but since I'm not looking for complex effects and since the rendering quality of quake3 seems to be good enough to me, I wanted to ask what did the release of the quake3 engine changed for open source developpers (except the infamous invsqrt method).

I heard Carmack released it for students or people alike, but C++ is here: is quake3's code obsolete compared to Ogre's when it comes to learning ?

Comment: OOP doesn't make code any better, which seems to be what you're asking. If you want OOP, then it makes more sense to go with an OOP engine like Ogre, rather than trying to adapt something in a different paradigm to how you want it.

Comment: OOP makes Ogre reusable, but I don't know if that's the case with quake 3 since it's OOP with C, which makes write more code... I don't want OOP, I just want what is easier, considering quake 3 is far enough for me as a 3d engine...

Comment: Quake's code base is much more hackish than Ogre. For learning I would go for the latter.

Comment: Well written code in any language is easy to work with irrespective of the language.  Badly written code in any language is hard to work with irrespective of the language.

Comment: Quake's code isn't generic because it wasn't meant to be. It isn't the plain engine, it is a game. Also, all games tend toward "hackish" as ship dates loom, it is a fact of life :-P

Comment: More games have shipped based on id Tech 3 than have shipped based on Ogre. By any pragmatic measure, id Tech 3 is more generic.

Comment: Yes but if you are talking about FPS's that makes sense. On top of that open source doesn't always have a good reputation, while on the other side, quake 3 has a very good reputation. Ogre looks like it's more suited to do an RPG, a car game, a platform game, or even a flight simulator. I don't know a lot about quake 3's anatomy, but I feel safer with a scene manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want OO follow Ogre. Quake is more built for itself, messy, and seems like that had a tight deadline and didn't care about structure.

Comment: I wonder what Carmack thinks about ogre. And what sinbad thinks about the quake3 src release ;p